# Getting range of numbers

Tags: asp-classic

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I need to work out a range that a dynamic number sits in.

For example, i have a script like so

```
<% upperlimit = 50000.0 %>
<% lowerlimit = -30000.0 %>
<%=Int((upperlimit - lowerlimit + 1)*Rnd() + lowerlimit) %>
```

This spits out the value 30366.

The upperlimit and lowerlimit are dynamic so i dont know what the output would be.

This value is in the range 30001 - 40000 ... How can i get those values dynamically?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_rnd.asp) covers your situation:

```
<%
max=100
min=1
Randomize
%>
<%=Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)%>
```

**Update 1**

```
<% upperlimit = 50000.0 %>
<% lowerlimit = -30000.0 %>
<% range = 10000 %>
<% newValue =Int((upperlimit - lowerlimit + 1)*Rnd() + lowerlimit) %>
<% lowerBand=(newValue\range)*range %>
<% upperBand=lowerBand+range %>

<%=newValue%>
<br>
<%=lowerBand+1%>-<%=upperBand%>
```

Comment: That doesnt show the 2 dynamic ranges the randomised value sits in

Comment: @BigJobbies: what are the 2 dynamic ranges? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Im trying to find the 2 range values that the randomised number sits in ... So for my example, my code spits out the value 30366 ... Somehow i need my code to decide what range that sits in, which is 30001 - 40000 ... Those 2 numbers are what i need to find out.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to generate 30000-40000

```
<%
Dim MyNewRandomNum
Randomize
MyNewRandomNum = Int(Rnd * 10000)+30000
response.write MyNewRandomNum
%>
```

the value you random
30000 is minimal value
and 10000 is value you wanted to random (1-10000)

i hope this is you want

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, this is not what i want to acheive though ... I need to get the 2 range numbers in which my random number sits

Answer (score 0):

This works for both negative and positive values of **newValue**:

```
<%
dim  upperlimit, lowerlimit, newValue, lowerBand, upperBand

upperlimit = 50000.0
lowerlimit = -30000.0
Randomize
newValue = Int((upperlimit - lowerlimit + 1)*Rnd + lowerlimit)
lowerBand = Fix(newValue/10000) * 10000 + Sgn(newValue)
upperBand = Sgn(lowerBand) * 10000 + lowerBand - Sgn(newValue)

response.write "newValue: " & newValue & "<br>"
response.write "lowerBand: " & lowerBand & "<br>"
response.write "upperBand: " & upperBand & "<br>"
%>
```

Please see [Running example](http://www.marlenynunez.com/stackoverflow-questions-16930708-getting-range-of-numbers.asp)